# Uno Platform WCT DataGrid: is a macOS prerelease version available?

Tags: datagrid, windows-community-toolkit, uno-platform

The Uno Platform `DataGrid` is what I need, but it appears to not yet be available for macOS. Is there a prelease version available that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` control is available for all targets, including macOS. Make sure to properly reference the Uno Windows Community Toolkit NuGet package with the control in the macOS head:

```
<PackageReference Include="Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid" Version="7.0.0" />
```

With this, you should have access to the `DataGrid` control.